# Varbinary text representation to byte[]

Tags: c#, sql-server

In C#, how can I take the textual output that SQL Server Management Studio shows as the contents of a varbinary column, and turn that text into the byte[] that is stored in the column?

Answer (score 51):

OK, so you want to copy and paste the value displayed in SSMS for a varbinary column (e.g. "0x6100730064006600"), and get the byte[] from it in C#?

That's quite easy - the part after 0x is just hex values (2 characters each).  So, you take each pair, convert it to a number specifying a base of 16 (hex), and add it to a list, like so:

```
string stringFromSQL = "0x6100730064006600";
List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>();

string hexPart = stringFromSQL.Substring(2);
for (int i = 0; i < hexPart.Length / 2; i++)
{
    string hexNumber = hexPart.Substring(i * 2, 2);
    byteList.Add((byte)Convert.ToInt32(hexNumber, 16));
}

byte [] original = byteList.ToArray();
```

Disclaimer - fairly dodgy and unoptimal code, I just hacked it together for demonstration purposes (it should work though).

Comment: Why is your code unoptimal? It seems quite ok in my opinion :)

Comment: @Żubrówka - In terms of readability, it's not too bad; in terms of performance though, we could simply use an array though, since we know exactly how large it will need to be.  Using a different data structure and then .ToArray()-ing it seems a bit slack to me, but I did it mainly for clarity and readability :)

Comment: I tested out the difference between byte[] and List<byte> in .NET 4.5, and found List<byte> only took ~100ms more over 10,000 iterations.

Comment: best solution!!

Answer (score 8):

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select col from yourtable", conn);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        byte[] bytes = (byte[])reader[0];
    }
    reader.Close();
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you - but I want to cut and paste the text from the SQL Server Management Studio window.  I do not want to requery the database.

Comment: SSMS is a client application designed to display formatted data. It wouldn't have an interface to access the underlying binary data returned from the database. That's what the programmatic interface described in this answer is for. SSMS is the wrong tool for this.

Comment: @ChrisSmith I disagree - the textual content shown in SSMS textual representation of binary data fields is clearly related to the actual data stored in the field.

Comment: The content shown certainly is a representation of the binary data. The problem is that the tool isn't designed to make that underlying data available: the purpose of SSMS is to display the data in its formatted state only. SSMS may even be throwing away the binary data as soon as it calculates the display version.